# Why in this line of haskell, $ cannot replace ()

Tags: haskell

The code is

```
prime (x:xs) = x:prime (filter (\y -> y `mod` x /=0) xs)
```

If I change it to

```
prime (x:xs) = x:prime $ filter (\y -> y `mod` x /=0) xs
```

There is a pattern matching error.

Comment: It does *not* throw a pattern matching error. It throws a *type error*.

Comment: @pspencil: it's a misconception that `$` is a syntactic replacement for `()` — `$` is a function/operator; it's just the precedence rules that make `$` convenient in many cases — but there's no syntactic magic behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a misconception that `$` is a syntactic replacement for `()` — `$` is a regular operator (which itself is a function that is simply infix by default); it's just the precedence rules that make `$` convenient in many cases — but there's no syntactic magic behind it.

---

Now, ignoring the irrelevant bits, let's just concentrate on the part of the code that's causing the error:

```haskell
x :  prime (foo bar)
```

is the same as

```haskell
x : (prime (foo bar))
```

because the `:` on the left has a lower precedence than the function application on the right.

However

```haskell
x : prime   $  foo bar
```

is the same as

```haskell
(x : prime) $ (foo bar)
```

which is the same as

```haskell
(x : prime)   (foo bar)
```

because the `:` on the left has a higher precedence than the `$` on the right.

So the error comes from the fact that you're trying to apply the result of the expression `x : prime` to the argument `foo bar` as if `x : prime` were a function, but it's not, hence the type error.

Solution? Either throw in some parentheses, or even better, don't use the `$` at all in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If I try to reproduce the error, it seems like GHC understands it like so:

```
(x : prime) $ filter (\y -> y `mod` x /= 0) xs
```

But you want it like that:

```
x : (prime $ filter (\y -> y `mod` x /= 0) xs)
```

So you just have to use bracket notation, I think.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
x : prime $ filter foo xs
```

It is interpreted as

```
(x : prime) $ filter foo xs
```

due to `(:)` having a higher precedence than `($)`. See the fixity declarations section of [this report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#Fixity_declarations) for more.

It fails because a list of functions (`(x:prime)`) is not a function, and cannot be used as such.

---

If you want to make the function prettier, try this:

```
prime (x:xs) = x : prime (filter ((/= 0) . (`mod` x)) xs)
```

Comment: `flip mod 0`? Are you sure? Shouldn't it be `flip mod x`? Moreover I'd probably write `(/= 0)` instead of `(/=) 0`. And note that you calso replace `flip mod x` with ```(`mod` x)```, so in the end: you get ```((/= 0) . (`mod` x))```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained the problem. Here is one solution:

```
prime (x:xs) = (x:) $ prime $ filter (\y -> y `mod` x /=0) xs
```

That is, you can use an *operator section* to express the application of `:` to `x` and then apply the result as you like.

Comment: Or: `(x:) . prime $ ...`

Comment: @Bakuriu, I decided against that for this question.